# Matplotlib xlim interfering with graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

When I comment out the plt.xlim(2004, 2017) I see the graph but without the correct x-axis. But when it isn't commented, I see the correct x-axis but without the graph.

Is there a way to combine them so the graph is visible with the correct x-axis?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 0, 'display.max_columns', 0)

df = pd.read_csv('PakistanDroneAttacksWithTemp.csv', encoding='latin1')

df = df[['Date', 'Al-Qaeda', 'Taliban', 'Civilians Max', 'Total Died Max']]

df['Terrorists Killed'] = (df['Al-Qaeda'] + df['Taliban'])

df = df[['Date', 'Terrorists Killed', 'Civilians Max', 'Total Died Max']]

df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
df.drop(df.index[397], inplace=True)


df['Civilians Max'].plot()
df['Terrorists Killed'].plot()
df['Total Died Max'].plot()
plt.legend(loc=4)
plt.xlim(2004, 2017)
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Deaths')
plt.show()
```

[Input Data (df.head(20))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Xk0m.png)

Comment: Provide a sample input file that reproduces this problem please. Cut it down to a dozen lines or fewer if you can.

Comment: Have you tried calling xlim() before doing the actual plotting? Will need sample input data to give better diagnostic

Comment: added some input to make my question easier to visualize

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a list of the `[low, high]` limits to `plt.xlim`:

```
plt.xlim([2004, 2017])
```